# Javascript Clickable Icon Instead of Pop Up

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day sir. Help me to fix this. This code is just automatically pop up when I open the page. How can I convert this to clickable instead of automatically pop up.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.klaviyo.com/media/js/public/klaviyo_subscribe.js">   </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    KlaviyoSubscribe.attachModalSignUp({
        list: 'g9cZtX',
        delay_seconds: 0.5,
        content: {
            clazz: ' klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX',
            header: "Interested in our Newsletter?",
            subheader: "Stay in the know with news and promotions.",
            button: "Subscribe",
            success: "Thanks! Check your email for a confirmation.",
            styles: '.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX {  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial}.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_header {  color:#222;}.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_subheader {  color:#222;}.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_submit_button,.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_submit_button span {  background-color:#07234F;  background-image: none;   border-radius: 2px;}.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_submit_button:hover,.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_submit_button span:hover {  background-color:#2A4D85;  background-image: none; }.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_inner,.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_fieldset .klaviyo_field_group input[type=text],.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_fieldset .klaviyo_field_group input[type=email] {  border-radius: 2px;}'
        }
    });
```

Here is the clickable icon

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope icon-2x"></i></a></li>
```

Help to me to figure this out.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use click() to do that or use .on('click') .. like this change your class to icon_png instead of icon.png

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.icon_png').on('click',function(){
     KlaviyoSubscribe.attachModalSignUp({
            list: 'g9cZtX',
            delay_seconds: 0.5,
            content: {
                clazz: ' klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX',
                header: "Interested in our Newsletter?",
                subheader: "Stay in the know with news and promotions.",
                button: "Subscribe",
                success: "Thanks! Check your email for a confirmation.",
                styles: '.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX {  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial}.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_header {  color:#222;}.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_subheader {  color:#222;}.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_submit_button,.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_submit_button span {  background-color:#07234F;  background-image: none;   border-radius: 2px;}.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_submit_button:hover,.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_submit_button span:hover {  background-color:#2A4D85;  background-image: none; }.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_inner,.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_fieldset .klaviyo_field_group input[type=text],.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_fieldset .klaviyo_field_group input[type=email] {  border-radius: 2px;}'
            }
        });
    });
    });
```

Comment: the selector has to be `.icon\\.png`

Comment: @Dr.Molle good edit. but I didn't want to make that cause the OP dosn't know the click event how can he understand that slashes .. I don't want him to become confused later :)

Comment: Sir nothing happens in my result. :(

Comment: So I did wrong. That is not a png or jpeg it's <i class="icon-envelope icon-2x"></i>

Comment: sir help me sir. Nothing happens when I click that <i class="icon-envelope icon-2x"></i> image.